# Trying to pass an item and subitem with a button

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-listview

I am trying to pass values from an EditText (item and Subitem)
with a Button to a listview

I am able to view the TextView, but is there a way to pass the EditText to the TextView with onClick and send that TextView to the listview

Here is my XML file

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/results_listview"
        android:layout_width="323dp"
        android:layout_height="369dp"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.58" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/AddButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.921"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/results_listview"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.084" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/taskText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/enter_task_title"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/results_listview"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.243"

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/descriptionText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/enter_description"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/results_listview"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/taskText"

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="21sp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
```

This is my mainActivity

I have tried many different suggestions on others post, but none have been succesful.
I feel like i may be missing something obvious.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText taskText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.taskText);
        final EditText descText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.descriptionText);
        final TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        final TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
        Button AddButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddButton);
        final ListView resultsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.results_listview);


        final HashMap<String, String> nameAddresses = new HashMap<>();
        nameAddresses.put("item", "Subitem");
        nameAddresses.put("fgfdg", "fgdg");


        final List<HashMap<String, String>> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listItems, R.layout.list_item,
                new String[]{"First Line", "Second Line"},
                new int[]{R.id.text1, R.id.text2});

        final SimpleAdapter adapter1 = new SimpleAdapter(this, listItems, R.layout.list_item,
                new String[]{"First Line", "Second Line"},
                new int[]{R.id.taskText, R.id.descriptionText});

        final Iterator it = nameAddresses.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext())
        {
            HashMap<String, String> resultsMap = new HashMap<>();
            Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            resultsMap.put("First Line", pair.getKey().toString());
            resultsMap.put("Second Line", pair.getValue().toString());
            listItems.add(resultsMap);
        }
        resultsListView.setAdapter(adapter);


        AddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String task = taskText.getText().toString();
                String description = descText.getText().toString();

                HashMap<String, String> nameAddresses = new HashMap<>();
                nameAddresses.put("task", "description");

                nameAddresses.put(task, description);


                resultsListView.setAdapter(adapter1);
                adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                //listItems.add(adapter);

            }

        });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a list of all items you want in the adapter, right now you aren’t adding the new values to the adapters list

```
HashMap<String, String> nameAddresses = new HashMap<>();
            nameAddresses.put("task", "description");

            nameAddresses.put(task, description);


            resultsListView.setAdapter(adapter1);
            adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This code doesn’t touch the adapters list and therefore doesn’t add it to the list.

At the top of your class initialise a list of items that you want in the list, then when you create the adapter set that list to be the list the adapter uses to draw its items, when you’re pressing the “Add Button” make sure to simply

```
 list.put(“new”, “item”); 
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Because the list is linked to the adapter it will redraw the item list that it previously had (which is “list”), so no need to create new lists or new adapters